# R / nse / Double-handover of a variable to a sub-function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, nse, direct-labels

I have two functions I want to wrap together in a wrapping function for usability. The wrapping function includes a variable (a column name within a dataframe) which should be handed over from the wrapping function to one of the subfunctions.

Strongly reduced example:

### Subfunction 1: Create data

```
datafun <- function() {

    df_data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:20, 3), 
                          y = rnorm(60),
                          ga = sample(c("a", "b"), 30, replace = TRUE),
                          gb = sample(c("x", "y"), 20, replace = TRUE))

    df_data
}
```

### Subfunction 2: Plotting

```
plotfun <- function(df, gvar) {

    gvar_q = deparse(substitute(gvar))

    g <- ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color = gvar_q)) +
        ggplot2::geom_line() +
        directlabels::geom_dl(ggplot2::aes(label = {{gvar}}), method = list("last.points"))

    g
}
```

### Wrapping function

```
wrapfun <- function(gvar) {

    dat <- datafun()
    plot <- plotfun(df = dat, gvar = {{gvar}})

    plot
}
```

### Testing

Using the two subfunctions directly works without a problem:

```
#works
d <- datafun()
plotfun(d, gvar = ga)
```

Using the wrapping function however leads to an error

```
# doesn't work
wrapfun(gvar = ga)
>Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ga' not found
```

Note that (as far as I have understood), `directlabels::geom_dl` does not accept `aes_string` as workaround. So it seems I can't hand over `gvar` as a string to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest versions of `ggplot`, you don't use `deparse/substitute` or `aes_string`. You use the new quasinotation syntax exclusively. With this example you should do just

```
plotfun <- function(df, gvar) {

   ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, color = {{gvar}})) +
     ggplot2::geom_line() +
     directlabels::geom_dl(ggplot2::aes(label = {{gvar}}), method = list("last.points"))

}
```

Then your function will work both directly and within `wrapfun()`

Comment: That works - but your code contains some remnants from `aes_string`. It should be:
```
plotfun <- function(df, gvar) {
 
 g <- ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, color = {{gvar}})) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  directlabels::geom_dl(ggplot2::aes(label = {{gvar}}), method = list("last.points"))
 
 g
}

```

Comment: @TimmS. You are right. Sorry about that. Removed the quotes.